# How to update all the elements in a double array in X86?

Tags: c, arrays, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I am a newbie of X86 and I am stuck on updating a double array using the values of another double array. The following code is my function and I want to use inline assembly to replace the piece of code inside the loop. I have attached the error message below. Can anyone helps me to point out my errors? I am confused about the error messages and don't know how to revise it.

```
static inline void update(double * x,double * y,double * z,double * vx,
        double * vy,double * vz,uint32_t size){
        for (uint32_t i=0;i<size;++i){
            x[i] = x[i] + vx[i];
            y[i] = y[i] + vy[i];
            z[i] = z[i] + vz[i];
        }
}
uint32_t counter = 0;
__asm__ __volatile__ (  
    "loop: \n\t" 
    "faddq (%4), (%1)\n\t"
    "faddq (%5), (%2)\n\t"
    "faddq (%6), (%3)\n\t"
    "addq $8, %1\n\t"
    "addq $8, %2\n\t"
    "addq $8, %3\n\t"
    "addq $8, %4\n\t"
    "addq $8, %5\n\t"
    "addq $8, %6\n\t"
    "incq %0\n\t"
    "cmp %0, %7\n\t"
    "jne loopb"
    : "+r"(counter)
    : "r" (x),"r" (y),"r"(z),"r"(vx),"r"(vy),"r"(vz),"r"(size) 
    : "memory", "cc");
```

Error Messages:

```
update_locations_ass.c:150:15: error: invalid instruction mnemonic 'faddq'
        "loop: \n\t" 
                 ^
<inline asm>:2:2: note: instantiated into assembly here
        faddq (%rdi), (%rcx)
        ^~~~~
update_locations_ass.c:151:25: error: invalid instruction mnemonic 'faddq'
        "faddq (%4), (%1)\n\t"
                           ^
<inline asm>:3:2: note: instantiated into assembly here
        faddq (%r8), (%rdx)
        ^~~~~
update_locations_ass.c:152:28: error: invalid instruction mnemonic 'faddq'
        "faddq (%5), (%2)\n\t"
                           ^
<inline asm>:4:2: note: instantiated into assembly here
        faddq (%r9), (%rsi)
        ^~~~~
update_locations_ass.c:159:23: error: invalid operand for instruction
        "addq $8, %6\n\t"
                      ^
<inline asm>:11:7: note: instantiated into assembly here
        incq %eax
```

Compiler version:
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
Thread model: posix

Comment: What compiler are you using? Please don't post screenshots of error messages. Copy and paste them into your question. Also why are you writing this in assembly? The compiler can generate better code.

Comment: It is not recognizing the `faddq` instruction. Probably your compiler doesn't have FPU support..

Comment: The compiler is clang-602.0.53

Comment: @EugeneSh. it doesn't even exist, not the compiler's fault

Comment: Unless the data is always in L1, this kernel is bandwidth bound and not worthy of time wasted writing assembly instead of C.

Comment: Note that `loop` is an x86 instruction.  Using it as a label name usually doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm equally confused here.  What is `faddq`, and where did you get it from?  Is it supposed to be `fadd`?  You can't use two memory operands with `fadd` anyway, so the code looks completely incorrect.  If you're curious about the correct way to do it, try compiling with `-S` and `-O2` so you can look at optimized compiler output.

If you want to get a faster version of the function, easiest to just do it in C anyway.  Assuming that the arrays don't overlap, here is a much faster version:

```
// Assuming x and vx do not overlap
void update1(double *restrict x, const double *restrict vx, unsigned count) {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        x[i] += vx[i];
    }
}

void update(/* ... */) {
    update1(x, vx, count);
    update1(y, vy, count);
    update1(z, vz, count);
}
```

If you compile with `-O3`, the compiler will generate code that uses `addpd`, depending on your compilation target.  This is going to be miles better than anything you could write yourself using the x87 FPU instructions.

These simple functions--just adding arrays to other arrays--are very easy for the compiler to optimize, so unless you are teaching yourself assembly language, just let the compiler do it for you.